# how can i get the name of formation with the number of employe?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the schema in my database

[image]

and the table formation is

[image]

and the table demandedormation is

[image]

the problem is when I  want to select the number of demands by name of formation
I execute this `SELECT idformation,COUNT(idemploye) FROM demandeformation GROUP by idformation`
but I get this
[image]

but what I want is the name of the formation instead of the idformation
thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join

```
    SELECT a.idformation, b.formationlibelle, COUNT(a.idemploye) 
    FROM demandeformation a
    INNER JOIN formation b on a.idformation  = b.idformation  
    GROUP by a.idformation, b.formationlibelle
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have your query a little backwards.  Try this:

```
SELECT f.formationlibelle, count(df.idemployee)
FROM formation f
INNER JOIN demandeformation df on df.idformation = f.id_formation
GROUP BY f.idformation
```

Or you can group by formationlibelle, and if so be sure to add the field to your select statement.